# How to enforce encapsulation with the Cake Pattern

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, cake-pattern

I've been reading a bit about the Cake Pattern in Scala (I know that is old stuff), and I cannot see or imagine an way to lock down the concrete classes, so dependencies don't leak from the classes where they are injected.

A simple and current example comes from the [play-reactive-mongo-db](https://github.com/jonasanso/play-reactive-mongo-db) activator template. In that app, the controllers use the [`ReactiveMongoComponents`](https://github.com/jonasanso/play-reactive-mongo-db/blob/master/app/controllers/CityController.scala) trait to get an instance of the driver `ReactiveMongoApi`.

Now, the problem is that the controller *inherits* has a public method to return an instance of `reactiveMongoApi` and as such breaking 2 fundamental principles: Encapsulation and Information Hiding. I know the example is not great (as a controller shouldn't access any data store), but the same applies if there would be domain services or repositories. I know that those classes (domain services, repositories, etc) would have a trait that defines the accessible methods, and there wouldn't be a public method/attribute to get the dependency, but the concrete implementation does leak.

TL;DR: Cake pattern leaks dependencies from concrete implementations, how can this be avoided?

Comment: OK, this really isn't an answer to your question, but one approach is to [scrap your cake pattern](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2013/10/21/reader-monad-for-dependency-injection/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jwvh, I'll give that blog a good read and try to use it in one of my pet projects.